# How to pass model name to function and change its value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This does seem to me a pretty straight forward question but for some reason I am unable to find a solution after much searching. Pardon me if its a duplicate.

The question is that I would like to pass a 'model' to a function and change its value there.

So in the HTML I have this:

```
<input type='button' value='click here'
       ng-click="CreatePlayer.toggleSidenav(CreatePlayer.someVal)" />
```

And the function inside the controller is:

```
CreatePlayer.toggleSidenav = function(target) { }
```

Now, if I `console.log(target)`
I do get the current value of this model. But if I set `target = 'blah';` It doesn't update the value in the HTML.

Can someone please help me understand what am I doing wrong here?

Thank you.

**Update**
Thank you all for the time you gave to read the question. 
Here is a JS fiddle that I just wrote to explain my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/ibnyusrat/564f7x9p/

The issue is, inside of the controller there is a function and inside of that function I am able to read the value passed as a parameter but I am not able to set it to another value. I don't want to create a new function for every situation. Preferably I would like to use the same function and only pass a different model as a parameter to apply whatever it is that I want to do with its value. Can anyone please help me understand what am I doing wrong?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Complete – Provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem. Show the controller and how it is instantiated: controllerAs syntax or vanilla syntax? Is `CreatePlayer` attached to $scope or the `this` context of the controller?

Comment: @georgeawg Added JS Fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the template pass the name of the scope variable as a string argument:

```
<div ng-controller="CreatePlayerController as CreatePlayer">
    {{CreatePlayer.someVar}}
    <input type='button' value='click here'
           ng-click='CreatePlayer.updateValueOf("someVar")' />
</div>
```

In the controller, use [property accessor bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) to change the value:

```
this.updateValueOf = function updateValueOf(target){
  this[target] = 'Some other value.';
};
```

The [DEMO on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c6054vuy/)

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You no need to pass value to function , because your model value change automatically $scope variable updated.

```
<input type='button' value='click here'ng-click="CreatePlayer.toggleSidenav()" />
```

In controller set your value;

$scope.CreatePlayer.CreatePlayer ="blash";

Comment: The problem is I want to use the same function to manage multiple scope variables and perform an action on all of those. Please check the attached JS Fiddle.

Comment: HTML change as bellow,

      <input type='button' value='click here'ng-click='CreatePlayer.updateValueOf("someVar")'  />

In controller set your value;

    CreatePlayer.updateValueOf = function(target){
          console.log(CreatePlayer.someVar);
          CreatePlayer[target] ="test"
          console.log(CreatePlayer.someVar);
        }